# Predicting a single value in classification network

Tags: python, neural-network, classification

I am currently trying to get into machine learning and neural networks, but my lack of programming skills is kind of hindering me at the moment. I am following an online tutorial in which these lines of code were made to evaluate the created model:

```
pred_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_test,batch_size=len(X_test),shuffle=False)

predictions = list(model.predict(input_fn=pred_fn))

predictions[0]

final_preds = []
for pred in predictions:
    final_preds.append(pred['class_ids'][0])

final_preds[:10]

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(y_test,final_preds))
```

This works very well for me an tells me the precision I achieved on these 10 inputs I chose from `X_test`. Unfortunately, I can't really figure out how to be able to predict a particular, single value from `X_test` or maybe even a manually input value that has the same dimensions as an element of `X_test`.

`X_test` is a `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and includes 15 columns and thousands of rows. Therefore, I would find it helpful to maybe predict or evaluate a certain value.

If I missed any essential information, that I should have included, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take sections of the X_test dataframe, or pass in single values as a dataframe with a single row.

Sectioning a dataframe:

```
temp = X_test[i:i+1]
```

to test with the ith row, use temp now instead of X_test.

Or create a new dataframe with required data:

```
temp = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns = X_test.columns)
```

where data is input as a list (iterable) [[a1,a2,a3...a15]].

again use temp instead of X_test in your code.

Comment: Hej, I tried your first approach and firstly receive the data of a single row as promised. The temp variable is then used in my prediction function instead of X_test and batch_size changed to len(temp). When further progressing, I now get the error "TypeError: data must be either a numpy array or pandas DataFrame if pandas is installed; got Series" in the second block in which I save the prediction as a list in the predictions variable. Basically all I want is to see the predicted accuracy for this one row

Comment: I think I managed now. I used your second approach, creating a new DataFrame and then appending whatever columns I want into it. Then this is entered into the predict function and I receive my output. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that the function won't accept a series so I have updated the answer to return a dataframe in the first approach. Glad that the second approach worked.